# QEMU UEFI Application consistently returns invalid parameters for SetTimer

Tags: operating-system, kernel, qemu, uefi

I'm running a classic example of setting a timer for a uefi application which runs on qemu. 
The code I'm running:

```
#include <efi.h>
#include <efilib.h>
#include <eficon.h>

#define second 10000000
EFI_STATUS
EFIAPI
efi_main (EFI_HANDLE img, EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE *sys) {
  EFI_EVENT timer_event;
  EFI_STATUS stat;
  InitializeLib(img, sys);
  // This succeeds, though I've tried with EVT_TIMER and EFI_EVENT_TIMER
  stat = sys->
           BootServices->CreateEvent(EVT_TIMER, TPL_APPLICATION, NULL, 
                                      NULL, &timer_event);
  // This returns 2 == invalid parameter, however I want SetTimer to 
  // return 0 == success
  stat = sys->
            BootServices->SetTimer(timer_event, TimerRelative, 10000);
  if (stat == EFI_INVALID_PARAMETER) Print(L"This always prints :(");
  while(1){}
  return EFI_SUCCESS;
}
```

The command that I launch is such:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -smp 3 -rtc clock=host -nographic -enable-kvm -m 4096 -cpu host -usb -device usb-kbd -drive if=pflash,format=raw,readonly,file=/usr/share/edk2.git/ovmf-x64/OVMF-pure-efi.fd -drive file=$BASE_DIR/qos.img,index=0,format=raw
```

After reading the specs, edk2 source and example references I'm not sure what could be causing this issue but it looks like I'm doing the right thing here. Is there something weird in my setup? I've reduced the code to the simplest thing here. Maybe there's a bug?

Comment: What happens when you run on baremetal or with KVM disabled?

Comment: Since you're debugging on top of an OVMF you've built yourself, it may be worth looking at (and debugging or instrumenting) the `CoreSetTimer` function in MdeModulePkg/Core/Dxe/Event/Timer.c.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. After ripping off the structs like IEvent and using it to print values of timer_event, I'm finding that CreateEvent is doing anything which is bizarre. The values don't change between create event instantiations.

Comment: @AlexanderZhak I tried disabling KVM and it crashes without it, saying that it's required for my system to run the application.

Answer (score 0):

`NotifyTpl = TPL_APPLICATION` makes no sense in `CreateEvent()`. You need to use at least `TPL_CALLBACK`. Please refer to "Table 23. TPL Restrictions" in the [UEFI-2.7](http://www.uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI%20Spec%202_7_A%20Sept%206.pdf) spec, which includes "Event Notification Levels > TPL_APPLICATION".

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question for the following reasons: a) OP doesn't create any notify events which will use callbacks to interrupt the main process; b) Table you refer to states `< TPL_HIGH_LEVEL` for both `CreateEvent()` and `SetTimer()` functions; c) even if that doesn't have common sense, it's not the reason for code not to work correctly

Comment: TPL_APPLICATION is required by the spec when using WaitForEvent. Otherwise you will get invalid params.

Comment: @TaylorKaplan. Not quite right.  The spec states "This function must be called at priority level TPL_APPLICATION. If an attempt is made to call it at any other priority level, EFI_UNSUPPORTED is returned."

Comment: Thank you for the correction; indeed I failed to recall the following passage from the spec: "The `EVT_NOTIFY_WAIT` and `EVT_NOTIFY_SIGNAL` flags are exclusive. If neither flag is specified, the caller does not require any notification concerning the event and the *NotifyTpl*,
*NotifyFunction*, and *NotifyContext* parameters are ignored." Therefore, given that `Type = EVT_TIMER` only, `NotifyTpl = TPL_APPLICATION` is indeed irrelevant.